# Access 2010 VBA - Error "No coinciden los tipos" en IF

Tags: vba, ms-access

En un código VBA de un botón de un formulario de Access, tengo el siguiente código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado es un error como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿A qué se debe y cómo resolverlo?

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo [edit] tu pregunta y añadir el código en vez de una imagen del mismo. También, si eres nuevo, te invito a hacer el [tour] y a visitar [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero, **siempre que pongas código, ponlo como texto, nunca como imagen, por favor.**.

Lo segundo, utilizas `IsNull` solamente una vez. Pero viendo tu código, entiendo que quieres comprobar si alguno de los 4 campos es nulo. Tal cual lo tienes escrito, solamente estás comprobando el primero. La sentencia correcta sería algo así como:

`If IsNull(campo1) = True Or IsNull(campo2) = True Or IsNull(campo3) = True Or IsNull(campo4) = True Then`

Lo copiaría con tus datos, pero como has puesto el código como imagen.... ;)

Comment: Entendido! Buena respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Al realizar ese tipo de validaciones, como buena practica, te recomiendo dos formas;

*La que muestras en tu pregunta:

```
If Nz(fieldString, "") = "" Or Nz(FirldNumeric, 0) = 0, Or Nz(FieldVariant, "") = "" Then
     MsgBox "Lo que tenga que ocurrir...", vbInformation + vbokonly, "Ejemplo"
End If
```

*La forma que yo te recomiendo:
En lo personal, yo preferiria realizar las validaciones por separado, por una razon, ya que luego el entorno de vba de acceess almacena ciertas cosas en Cache, no te ha sucedido que de repente ¿no te marca los errores?, o se salta alguna validacion en estos "If Then Else End If", Yo para asegurar la calidad del codigo prefiero esto:

```
If Nz(Fieldstring, "") = "" Then
    MagBox "Lo que tenga que pasar.", vbInformation + vbokonly, "Error"
    Exit Sub/Function 
End If

If Nz(FieldNumeric, 0) = 0 Then
    MagBox "Lo que tenga que pasar.", vbInformation + vbokonly, "Error"
    Exit Sub/Function         
End IF
```

Asi de esta forma, aseguras la calidad del funcionamiento de las validaciones, ahora, con respecto a tu error 13, este se produce cuando intentas meter un tipo de dato Variant a una tipo de dato especifico, es decir, un String en un Float, o integer o algun tipo de dato ageno a lo que esta establecido en el campo de la BD, te recomiendo que verifiques el dato que manipulas.